# similarity between graphs in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am working on GPS data and I have plotted the speed distribution across a time frame for 3 different moving objects. Data length is not the same for my 3 entities. i.e object 1 has 4500 rows and object 2 has 2700 for each attribute. moreover, time is in seconds, starting from the first measurement.

my code is as follows:

```
plot(object1$speed)
plot(object2$speed)
```

which gives me the following graphs:

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOrug.jpg)

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cShR7.jpg)

I am trying to find a way to compare them. that is measuring similarity. I am also trying to see if there is a similarity in some particular part of the distribution if not all. I do not want to correlate the distributions as this will give me just one value. I am trying to find similarities in all or part of the sequence.
does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why not just graph `object1$speed - object2$speed` where times are equal?

Comment: @Chris. do you mean just putting them on the same plot?
times may not be equal at all. what I am really trying to do is find similarity in their speed distribution pattern.

Comment: Perhaps you should read [this paper](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~tdang/file/TimeExplorer.pdf) by Dang and Wilkinson on comparing time series by a set of 11 common features. The latter author is the progenitor of the "grammar of graphics" as espoused in `ggplot2` or `plotly`.

Comment: correlation with a sliding window?

Comment: [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/how-to-statistically-compare-two-time-series) is a similar post to get you started

Comment: Please explain what you mean by the plots of two objects to be "similar."  (There are many possible different meanings, depending on what aspects of their trajectories you are studying.)